# SQL Query Optimization - Alternative ways

Tags: mysql

[image]

i need to fill this variables for a given *action_to* (it contains user id)

```
type_1_count = "select count(action_type) from action where action_type = 1 AND user_from = 13213"

type_2_count = "select count(action_type) from action where action_type = 2 AND user_from = 13213"

type_3_count = "select count(action_type) from action where action_type = 3 AND user_from = 13213"
```

or

```
$type_counts = "three count sub queries in single query"
```

usually we do, '**three count queries**' or '**three count sub queries in single query**'.

is there any better way that i can get the counts of the action types in a single query ?

Answer (score 3):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(action_type = 1) as type_1_count,
       sum(action_type = 2) as type_2_count,
       sum(action_type = 3) as type_3_count       
from action
where user_from = 13213;
```

Or, use `group by`:

```
select action_type, count(*) as cnt
from action
where user_from = 13213;
```

The difference is that the first query produces one row with the different counts.  The second produces one row per `action_type` in the data, with the count as the second column.

EDIT:

The expression `sum(action_type = 3)` counts the number of rows where `action_type` has the value of 3.  In MySQL, booleans are treated as integers in a numeric context, with true being 1 and false being 0.  So, `sum(action_type = 3)` counts the number of rows where the `action_type` takes on that value.

Comment: @SamuelCook . . . Of course.  `sum(1)` and `count(*)` do the same thing.

Comment: But what if `action_type` = 3. Won't each row get counted 3 times?

Comment: Nice clarification of how mysql interprets logical to 1/0 for summation purposes.